# How to create a chart of total number of analyzes made in months?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I created a customer management system with Django. Every user has several customers and every customer has several reports. Users make analyses of these reports and send them to a user. This process is `ApprovalProcess`. I have an `ApprovalProcess` model and I want to create a line chart that shows the total number of analyzes made in months during the year. (By using `begin_date`) How can I do that?

**Update**: I can display my data in the line chart truely, but it shows only the entered data. For example, in this year I have only two approval months but I want to display all months as legends. I will add a picture for understanding.

[image: my chart]

**models.py**

```
class ApprovalProcess(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='starter')
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def approval_context_processor(request):
 today = datetime.now()
 line_data = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(begin_date__year=today.year).values('begin_date__month').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('-id__count')  

#Print: <QuerySet [{'begin_date__month': 4, 'id__count': 7}, {'begin_date__month': 3, 'id__count': 1}]>
```

**dashboard.html**

```
...
<div class="chart-container" style="min-height: 375px">
    <canvas id="statisticsChart" ></canvas>
</div>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('statisticsChart').getContext('2d');

var number_analysis = []
var label_data = []

   {% for data in line_data %}
       number_analysis.push({{ data.id__count }})
       label_data.push( {{data.begin_date__month }})
    {% endfor %}

       var statisticsChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'line',
       data: {
           labels: label_data,
           datasets: [ {
               label: "# of Approval",
               borderColor: '#54bbf3',
               pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(84,187,243, 0.6)',
               pointRadius: 0,
               backgroundColor: 'rgba(84,187,243, 0.4)',
               legendColor: '#f3545d',
               fill: false,
               borderWidth: 1,
               data: number_analysis,
           }, ]
       },
       options : {
           responsive: true,
           maintainAspectRatio: false,
           legend: {
               display: true
           },
           tooltips: {
               bodySpacing: 5,
               mode:"nearest",
               intersect: 0,
               position:"nearest",
               xPadding:20,
               yPadding:20,
               caretPadding:10
           },
           layout:{
               padding:{left:5,right:5,top:15,bottom:15}
           },
           scales: {
               yAxes: [{
                   ticks: {
                       fontStyle: "500",
                       beginAtZero: true,
                       maxTicksLimit: 5,
                       padding: 10
                   },
                   gridLines: {
                       drawTicks: false,
                       display: false
                   }
               }],
               xAxes: [{
                   gridLines: {
                       zeroLineColor: "transparent"
                   },
                   ticks: {
                       padding: 10,
                       fontStyle: "500",


                   }
               }]
       },

</script>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem here..?

Comment: @Sumithran how can I display total number of approvals in month by month for a year in the line chart?

Comment: are having issues in the backend or frontend? it is not clear..

Comment: @Sumithran I have updated my question can you look again?